# Draw borders but not the last one

Tags: html, css, datatables, styles

I have a table and in these 2 columns I need to have a border, but in the last number I do not want it to have a border, I tried already "border-top: 1px solid #000;" but does not help.

My current CSS style:

```
.myStyle{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

I attach the 2 images:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3ey9.png)
i)In one I target with a skyblue arrow the border I do not want to have.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YFiY.jpg)
ii)In the other picture It is a yellow arrow and it is how it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```css
.myStyle:not(:last-child) {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

or

```css
.myStyle {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.myStyle:last-child {
   border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```